# Consuming a array of json objects in java webservice

Tags: java, json, jersey

I Have a java webservice with Jersey and maven, which gets an array of json objects via HTTP post that comes from my angular front end. My insert method works fine for 1 json object, but now i need to send an array and im getting error 400 while tryng. What im missing?

this is the HTTP post

```
    postNeuromotora(params){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type','application/json');
    return this.http.post(`${this.api}neuromotora/`,params,{
      headers: headers
  }).map(
    (res:Response) => {return res.json();}
  );

  }
```

this is the INSERT java method

```
public void insert(Neuromotora[] array) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
            Long id = null;
            String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO neuromotora(nervonome,latencia,amplitudedistal,amplitudeprox,velocidade,ondaf,pacienteid,ladonervo)"
                    + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING neuromotoraid";
            for(Neuromotora oferta : array ){
                   try{
                PreparedStatement stmt = this.con.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
                stmt.setString(1,oferta.getNervoNome());
                stmt.setString(2,oferta.getLatencia());
                stmt.setString(3,oferta.getAmplitudeDistal());
                stmt.setString(4,oferta.getAmplitutdeProx());
                stmt.setString(5, oferta.getVelocidade());
                stmt.setString(6, oferta.getOndaF());
                stmt.setInt(7,oferta.getPacienteid());
                stmt.setString(8,oferta.getLadoNervo());


                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    id = rs.getLong("neuromotoraid");
                }

                this.con.commit();        
                }
            catch(SQLException e){
                this.con.rollback();
                throw e;
                }
            }



                }
```

this is the post method on my Controller

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/neuromotora/")
    public Response createNeuromotora(Neuromotora[] n) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        neuromotoraDAO dao = new neuromotoraDAO();

        dao.insert(n);

        return Response
            .status(200)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
            .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
            .entity(n)
            .build();

    }
```

And this is the output of the json array that im sending via post (only wrote 2 properties cause i wasnt able to copy all of it)

[{"pacienteid":5,"nervonome":""},{"pacienteid":5,"nervonome":""}]

Stacktrace of the http : https://pastebin.com/AEjrmq2K

Comment: Use a `List` instead of an array, change the type of your parameter from `Neuromotora[] n`  to `List<Neuromotora> n`.

Comment: same result =/ https://pastebin.com/AEjrmq2K here is the full stacktrace of the error if u wanna take a look